# Safe way to avoid merge-commits?

Tags: git

My workflow typically consists of branching off of master (which is where everyone pushes/pull from/to). Periodically, I'll pull the latest from master, merging that into my feature branch so that I can ensure a nice fast-forward merge when I merge my feature to master. This step (merging master into my feature branch) creates a lot of merge commits. How can I **safely** avoid these? If it can be done, is there even a point in doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in the fact that you merge master into your feature branch. You shouldn't do that.

Instead, *rebase* the feature branch onto master: `git rebase master` while in the feature branch. This will rewrite the commits from that branch to be based on master and thus you can fast-forward-merge that branch into master after doing the rebase (where you'd fix conflicts due to recent changes in master which were no in your feature branch set)

Comment: I think it's also important to add that you must avoid rebasing a branch that is public. git rebase can quickly become a favorite feature but one must be careful with it when working with shared repos: http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/git-5.shtml.

Comment: True, but honestly, rebasing a WIP/feature branch - even if published e.g. for backup/codereview reasons - might not be such a big issue as long as everyone knows not to base any work on that branch.